# What's a comprehensive review of the implications of Bell-nonlocality on our notion of reality / Weltanschauung?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality, non-locality

I am looking for a (preferably peer-reviewed) article that summarizes:

- the historic debates surrounding Bell-nonlocality,
- how nonlocality can/not be reconciled with our notation of reality,
- and the theories (like many-worlds) that attempt to explain it

Comment: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bell-theorem/

Comment: I find http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bell%27s_theorem quite helpful for a start, although I guess it may lack the historical debates, it talks quite extensively on the physical meaning of Bell-nonlocality.